# How to make an download button which download files like pdf... in Android Studi

Tags: android-studio, button, download

I am making an app in which i want a download button which let user download my file. So how can i make a button like that?

Comment: File from your server ?

Comment: yep.. file from my server.....

http://www.kvafsojhar.net/admin/downloads/1430937066time_table_for_eiop_and_suppli.docx

Answer (score 0):

That are two Qestions...
So first you need a normal Button[do this in yourlayoutfile.yml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="198dp"
        android:text="Download" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now set a OnClickListener at your Button in youre Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button downloadButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        downloadButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               downloadFile();
            }
        });
    }

    public void downloadFile() {
        //Here put-in youre download stuff
        //so download the file from your server
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Gadget Guru  Need the download Code, too?

Comment: @GadgetGuru Here you find how to download http://stackoverflow.com/a/43750799/7938448

Answer (score 0):

create void downloadFile(URI uri) you have to use URI example -

```
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) 
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        request.setTitle("your tittle");
        request.setDescription("your description");
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);


        Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

in last set onclickmethod and write

```
Uri urifile = Uri.parse("your file address");
downloadfile(urifile);
```